# Xilinx ISE with ModelSim SE Linux configuration

Tags: xilinx, modelsim

Can somebody tell me how I can configure Xilinx ISE with ModelSim on linux?
As ModelSIM only comes for windows but is there a way to do configuration in Linux (using wine etc)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Modelsim comes in a Linux version.  Or are you using the xilinx-only version?

Comment: Yes but free student edition is only for windows.

Comment: In that case, can you use Xilinx's own simulator?

Comment: It is possible but ISE simulator comes with some limitations over ModelSim especially in terms of Interfaces with any target board. So far I am relaying on ISE Simulator.

Comment: I know this is late but there is a linux version of Modelsim called "vsim".
This probably won't help you anymore, however I hope to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this workaround:
http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modelsim-pe-student-edition/460FWEI9NBk

Seems like it's a lot of work to use Modelsim, but if you really don't like Xilinx ISE simulator it might be worth it.